# Discord.js sent message to all member in server?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Discord.js version : 11.4.2

sent message to everyone in server `Hello`

```
if(message.content === '!Hello'){
 message.sentall("Hello")
}
```

Comment: This is against discord TOS pretty sure.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Discord.js v11, I suppose that this is what you'll need :

```
const guild = client.guilds.get("YourGuildID");
guild.members.forEach(member => {
    member.send("YourMessageToSend");
});
```

Make sure to replace `YourGuildID` with the id of the guild you want to send the message to, and do the same thing with `YourMessageToSend` but, with the message you want to send this time.

Comment: `guild.members` isn't a `Collection` it's a `Manager`, change to `guild.members.cache.forEach`

Comment: @Karizma You're right, I've edited my answer, thank you for spotting this :)

Comment: Wait actually no we were both right, `guild.members` is a collection in v11, and that was what the OP was using. So you should add both options with labels for which version

Comment: @Karizma Indeed, let me fix that once again ;p